# Database Structure for Duplicate Users

Tags: database-design

Imagine we have a table "users" with users.id and some data.
We are running some scripts to identify if users are duplicates of another user. There is no such thing as a "master user" which the other accounts are related to.

Once identified we want to save these users belong to each other in an easy way that will allow us to run queries on these user ids easily in the future. Like "SELECT all duplicate users of user X".

We thought about a new table:

```
duplicate_users
- id
- user_id
- key
```

For each new entry to "users", we would also create an entry in "duplicate_users" with a random key. If users are identified as duplicates, keys for them will be updated to the same new value.

Is this a good idea? What is the best database structure to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Users table
    - usersid
    - username

RelatedUsers table
    - relatedusersid
    - usersid: foreign key to one of the usersid in the users table
    - usersid: foreign key to one of the usersid in the users table
```

So you have a table of related users.

Ex:

```
Users
    - 1: Joe
    - 2: Jack
    - 3: John

RelatedUsers
    - 1: 1, 2
    - 2: 1, 3
```

So we know that Jack and John are related to Joe.